# Suspicious iFrame in website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I have a website managed on Wordpress and since a few days, I see that on every pages, it tries to load a link at the bottom of the website like if it is always loading.
By inspecting the code, I saw that :

```
<iframe id="idadv" src="http://braip.com.br/wp-feed/2016/gondran/top10.php?modelo=2016&amp;user=baixarfilme&amp;url=www.swapiz.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It is actually the link it tries to load and it looks SO SUSPICIOUS ! I have NO third party plugin on it that is not a verified one (I actually have three very popular plugins).

Any idea what it is ? A Hack ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be some sort of comment.. Often times comment systems are managed through iframes.

I would check in wordpress and see if you have any new comments or plugins that manage comments.

If you do have a comment related plugin I suggest you uninstall it and try reinstall it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ! I will check that out !